# Copying from a specific range in Excel using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, pivot-table

I am currently building a program where I copy a pivot table from one workbook and copy it into another, and am currently having trouble copying the table, as the number of rows depends on how many people buys a product every month. I tried using a UsedRange on that specific range, and it didn't work. Something along these lines...

```
    targetSheet.Range("N3:S50").UsedRange.Copy()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you used UsedRange, and it didn't work, did you get an error, or did it just get the wrong Range?

Comment: Do you recall the error?  It may help figuring out what the issue was.

Comment: COMException was Unhandled: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code grabs the data for a particular sheet (in this case tSheet).  It then finds the upper-left cell address, copies all data, deletes everything from the spreadsheet, and then pastes it back.  This has the effect of resetting the UsedRange on a particular sheet.

```
Dim values 'holds info on the usedRange of the current spreadsheet
Dim usedRangeAddress As String 'holds the address of the usedRange of the current spreadsheet (i.e. "A1")
usedRangeAddress = tSheet.UsedRange.Address 'get the upper most left cell address
values = tSheet.UsedRange.Value'Store values of all cells to array.     
tSheet.Cells.Delete() 'Delete all cells in the sheet     
tSheet.Range(usedRangeAddress).Value = values'Restore values to their initial locations
```

So, with this, you should be able to utilize the first line of code, and then a second line to paste to your otherSheet

```
Dim values 'holds info on the usedRange of the current spreadsheet
values = tSheet.UsedRange.Value'Store values of all cells to array.     
otherSheet.Range(yourTargetAddress).Value = values
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll test it out real quick to see if it'll work.

Comment: Tried it out, looks I can use this and edit it around to fit what I need. Much thanks, bro!

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A1:B2").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: That would work, but as I said, the range could by anywhere from A1:B2 to A1:B50, the program relies on the spreadsheet data to figure that out, thus I need something that can detect how many cells are used and copy that, not just hard-coding a range in. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough.